# Can MongoDB WiredTiger engine be used for pre-aggregated reports? (similar to MMAPv1)

Tags: database, mongodb

One of the use cases page on the mongodb documentation shows an example of creating pre-aggregated reports with very large amounts of data:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/

The document clearly states this is only for MMAPv1 engine, as far as WiredTiger goes, there's no additional info of the trade-offs or how would one approach this use cases otherwise.

There's also the macro overview of a design for such a use case: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb
But this displays pretty much the same approach as the use-case link above.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-4894 has some details. Apparently the title is a bit misleading as it applies to half of the page only:

> The page defines 4 key patterns:
>
> 1. Pre-aggregation (update averages/mins/maxs for each consumed event rather than recording raw event).
> 2. Bucketing (grouping sets of records together, eg. by day, for fast subsequent access - the pattern to deal with consuming lots of fine grained events and then servicing analytics/reports that want to retrieve coarse grained data).
> 3. Pre-allocation (aka. pre-padding, to avoid excessive document growth and re-allocation)
> 4. Intra-document-hierarchy (to prevent event ingestion latencies from increasing as the time of each day increases)
>
> With the introduction of WiredTiger, it is likely that **pattern 3 (Pre-allocation)** is no longer required and perhaps would even be detrimental, due to the way WiredTiger deals with "in-place updates" internally. Also it could be that **pattern 4 (intra-document hierarchy)** also adds no value when using WiredTiger (this needs to be validated by someone).

It seems pre-aggregation (also described in the blog post) and bucketing are still valid patterns.

Comment: The thing is, the issue you linked was closed. But the documentation is still vague -_-"